# Why in Teichmüller-Tukey lemma finiteness is essential?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, axiom-of-choice

First we will state a Teichmüller-Tukey Lemma:

> Let $A$ be a set and $\phi$ be a property defined on all finite subset of $A$. Assume that $B$ is a subset of $A$ such that each finite subset of $B$ have property $\phi$. Then $B$ can be extended to a maximal subset $M$ of $A$ such that each finite subset of $M$ has a property $\phi$.

My question is :- In the statement there is condition of **finite**. In case we have **countable** why we could not show that its equivalent with the axiom of choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you try to build a maximal subset by transfinite induction, the process breaks down at limit stages. An obvious counterexample would be: Let $A$ be the set of positive real numbers. For a countable subset $X$ of $A$, define $\phi$ by: $X$ satisfies $\phi$ iff the sum of all members of $X$ is finite.